# Помогите с оптимизацией кода у парсера

Tags: python

В меру своих знаний и помощи местных гуру, пытаюсь написать  парсер, который фильтрует запрос и парсит значение ключа записывая его текстовый файл в котором удаляются дубли строк.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
x = response.json()
 
        
x['result']['Info'] = list(filter(lambda y: y['country'] in ('Br', 'It'), x['result']['Info']))




with open('parse.txt', 'a') as file:
    for item in x['result']['Info']:
        if item.get("Id"):
             file.write(f'{item.get("Id")}\n')
          
with open("parse.txt") as input_:
             result = dict.fromkeys(input_).keys()
    
with open("parse.txt", "w") as output:
             print(*result, file=output, sep="")
```

Из явной проблемы в текстовом файле записывается пустая строка(после повторного запуска).

Пример из вывода парсера

```
184355
624267
267537
476245
945637
```

При повторном запуске такой вид:

```
184355
624267
267537
476245
945637

930285
937583
```

Comment: У вас в ключе 'id' значение str или int? print(type( item.get("Id")) str или int?

Comment: в нем числовое значение. видимо это считается int?

Comment: {'id':184355} или {'id':'184355'}?

Comment: Первый вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = list(filter(lambda y: y['country'] in ('Br', 'It'), x['result']['Info']))
    
with open('parse.txt', 'a') as file:
# 1
    if file.tell():
        file.write('\n')    
    file.write('\n'.join(map(str, (item.get("Id") for item in x if item.get("Id")))))

# 2     
    if file.tell():
        file.seek(file.tell()-1)
    for item in x['result']['Info']:
        if item.get("Id"):
             file.write(f'{item.get("Id")}\n')
```

Comment: При выполнении первое и последнее числа наползают друг на друга, но пробела между строками нету.

Comment: Теперь все работает, но если файл пустой или заного создается  первая строка пустая. В любом случае Спасибо!

Comment: Подправил  ответ

Comment: Теперь идеально, каждое число с новой строки, без наползаний и пробелов.